# why we are using "var app = angular.module('myApp', []);" this? especially i need to know about square brackets in this line?

Tags: angularjs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
<br>
Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}
</div>
<script>
*var app = angular.module('myApp', []);*
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
});
</script>
```

why we are using "var app = angular.module('myApp', []);" this? especially i need to know about square brackets in this line???

Answer (score 4):

The first argument is the module name `myApp`. The second argument is an array of module names that this module depends on. Empty square brackets denotes that this module does not have any dependencies.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
```